# How to access cloud run environment variables in Dockerfile

Tags: docker, google-cloud-platform, environment-variables, google-cloud-run

I have built a containerised python application which runs without issue locally using a **.env** file and and a **docker-compose.yml** file compiled with **compose build.**

I am then able to use variables within the Dockerfile like this.

```
ARG APP_USR
ENV APP_USR ${APP_USR}

ARG APP_PASS
ENV APP_PASS ${APP__PASS}

RUN pip install https://${APP_USR}:${APP_PASS}@github.org/*****/master.zip
```

I am deploying to cloud run via a synced bitbucket repository, and have defined  under **"REVISIONS" > "SECRETS AND VARIABLES"**,(as described here: https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/configuring/environment-variables)
but I can not work out how to access these variables in the Dockerfile during build.

As I understand it, I need to create a cloudbuild.yaml file to define the variables, but I haven't been able to find a clear example of how to set this up using the Environment variables defined in cloud run.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My understanding is that it is not possible to *directly* use a Cloud Run revision's **environment variables** in the Dockerfile because the build is managed by Cloud Build, which doesn't know about Cloud Run revision before the deployment.

But I was able to use Secret Manager's **secrets** in the Dockerfile.

**Sources:**

- Passing secrets from Secret Manager to `cloudbuild.yaml`: https://cloud.google.com/build/docs/securing-builds/use-secrets
- Passing an environment variable from `cloudbuild.yaml` to `Dockerfile`: https://vsupalov.com/docker-build-pass-environment-variables/

**Quick summary:**

In your case, for `APP_USR` and `APP_PASS`:

1. Grant the Secret Manager Secret Accessor (roles/secretmanager.secretAccessor) IAM role for the secret to the Cloud Build service account (see first source).
2. Add an `availableSecrets` block at the end of the `cloudbuild.yaml` file (out of the `steps` block):

```yaml
availableSecrets:
  secretManager:
  - versionName: <APP_USR_SECRET_RESOURCE_ID_WITH_VERSION>
    env: 'APP_USR'
  - versionName: <APP_PASS_SECRET_RESOURCE_ID_WITH_VERSION>
    env: 'APP_PASS'
```

3. Pass the secrets to your build step (depends on how you summon `docker build`, Google's documentation uses 'bash', I use Docker directly):

```yaml
  - id: Build
    name: gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker
    args:
      - build
      - '-f=Dockerfile'
      - '.'

      # Add these two `--build-arg` params:

      - '--build-arg'
      - 'APP_USR=$$APP_USR'

      - '--build-arg'
      - 'APP_PASS=$$APP_PASS'

    secretEnv: ['APP_USR', 'APP_PASS'] # <=== add this line
```

4. Use these secrets as standard environment variables in your `Dockerfile`:

```
ARG APP_USR
ENV APP_USR $APP_USR

ARG APP_PASS
ENV APP_PASS $APP_PASS

RUN pip install https://$APP_USR:$APP_PASS@github.org/*****/master.zip
```

Answer (score 3):

You have several way to achieve that.

You can, indeed, create your container with your .env in it. But it's not a good practice because your .env can contain secret (API Key, database password,...) and because your container is tight to an environment

The other solution is to deploy your container on Cloud Run (not a docker compose, it doesn't work on Cloud Run), and [add the environment variable with the revision](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/configuring/environment-variables). use, for example, `--set-env-vars=KEY1=Value1` format to achieve that.

If you have secrets, you can store them in [secret manager and load it as env var at runtime, or as volume](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/configuring/secrets)

The last solution, if you can specify where your container will get the .env file in your file tree (I'm not expert in Python to help you on that), you can use this trick that [I described in this article](https://medium.com/google-cloud/mount-a-file-as-a-volume-in-cloud-run-facc74c02cc6). It's perfectly designed for configuration file, it's stored natively in Secret manager and therefore protect your secret automatically.

Comment: I already added my environment variables in a revision via the the console, as described in the first part of the first part of the link you  gave, but references to these variable in Dockerfile or my python code do not work.

Comment: You have different step: build and run. At build time, you can pass argument that you can set as ENV in your Dockerfile. However, the CLoud Run env var definition will override these values; consider that more as "default value if nothing is provided". Then at runtime, you can set env var and get them as any environment variables, no difference if it's locally set, set in the Dockerfile (default values) or in the Cloud Run revision. `os.getenv('KEY')` in python

Comment: I forgot a very important point: after the build, the dockerfile no longer exist, you only have your container with (or without) default env var set. Your dockerfile isn't evaluated at runtime.

Comment: Thanks for the follow up!   I currently have the ARG and ENV fields set as shown above for ARG/ENV APP_USR and  ARG/ENV APP_PASS (these are the only variables used at build time to install a package).  I also have some other env vars (all env vars for both the build and runtime have been added as a revision in console), which I am referencing in the code using os.getenv('KEY'), but currently these fields are showing as empty both in build time and at runtime.

Comment: Inspecting the current revisions YAML, I can see that the variables are def under containers >  image >  env - in name value pairs. -  name: APP_USR  value: **** -name: APP_PASS value:****. but I still can't seem to reference it at build time or at runtime

Comment: The env variables are now available at run time, so it is only the docker vars I am missing.

Comment: Did you find how to get your env vars in the Dockerfile?